# SED replace everything not in between quotes

Tags: unix, sed

I have a repeating list of this text, and the "testestewst" is unique for each item in the list:

```
testestetet *testest = [testeeste qtestest:@"I need this text"];
[testesteste:@"I need this text"];
[stesteset atestestest];
```

How in the world do I do a SED replace to remove everything but the text I need?

Comment: So, the output should be two lines which each say "I need this text"?

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/g' < test > result
```

works at least if you only one of such item per line...
(replace 'test' and 'result' with the names of input and output files.

**EDIT** :

```
sed 's/^[^"]*$//g' < test | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/g' > result
```

Replaces also all lines without quotes with new lines...

Comment: Umm, this one prints lines that have no quoted strings on them like the last line in the example.

Comment: This works great in zsh, with the quote plugin, I didn't want the messy special chars of the colon and the quote, so I made this: `alias quote="quote | sed 's/.*“\(.*\)”.*/\1/g'"`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking for, this should work...I went to some trouble to only return quoted text on lines containing an @. If your goal can be accomplished by just pulling out quoted text then it's possibly simpler.

```
$ cat > t1.sed
/@/{
s/[^"]*@"//
s/".*//
p
}
d
$ sed -f t1.sed t1.dat
I need this text
I need this text
$
```

Comment: Using '`sed -n`' suppresses the normal 'print after each line' operation; then you just need the regexes, which could be combined, leading to: `sed -n '/@"/s/.*@"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/"/!{/\n/{P;b}};s/"/\n/g;D' inputfile
```

Example:

```
$ cat inputfile
aaa bbb "this is" eee
fff "what I" hhh
111 "want"
"to see"
222 333
"today" zzz
$ sed -n '/"/!{/\n/{P;b}};s/"/\n/g;D' inputfile
this is
what I
want
to see
today
```